# Python Threading Issues

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

I have been trying to get this thread to work, yet i cannot see why it doesnt work. I am running a non-malicious bot that does a few tasks and i wrote a small GUI for it to use. How would i thread these together? This is what i tried and didnt work:

Main Bot Code;

```
try:
    gui_thread = threading.Thread( target = execfile, args = ('GUI.py',) )
    gui_thread.start()

except:
    print('Unable to load GUI')
```

The GUI appears to load as the except isn't ran, and it continues to load the bot as planned, yet the GUI doesn't show like it does in the main GUI.py scrpit

GUI Code;

```
import Tkinter


class Geekster_Bot(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set("")

        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Update!",
                                command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)

        button2 = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Clear Whitelist",
                                command=self.OnButtonClick_Whitelist_Wipe)
        button2.grid(column=2,row=0)

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,
                              anchor="w",fg="white",bg="blue")
        label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable.set("Select Modpack!")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())       
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)


    def OnButtonClick(self):
        try:
            modpackdoc = open(r'E:\Geekster_Bot\Modpack.txt', 'w')
            modpackdoc.write(self.entryVariable.get())
            modpackdoc.close()
            self.labelVariable.set("Updated Modpack: " +self.entryVariable.get())
            self.entry.focus_set()
            self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)
        except:
            self.labelVariable.set("Unable to Update the Modpack file!")
            self.entry.focus_set()
            self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        try:
            modpackdoc = open(r'E:\Geekster_Bot\Modpack.txt', 'w')
            modpackdoc.write(self.entryVariable.get())
            modpackdoc.close()
            self.labelVariable.set("Updated Modpack: " +self.entryVariable.get())
            self.entry.focus_set()
            self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)
        except:
            self.labelVariable.set("Unable to Update the Modpack file!")
            self.entry.focus_set()
            self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnButtonClick_Whitelist_Wipe(self):
        try:
            execfile('command_whitelist_wipe.py')
            self.labelVariable.set("Whitelist Cleared")
            self.entry.focus_set()
            self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)
        except:
            self.labelVariable.set("Unable to Wipe Whitelist!")
            self.entry.focus_set()
            self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Geekster_Bot(None)
    app.title('Geekster_Bot')
    app.geometry('450x100')
    app.mainloop()
```

Both work without any issues! The GUI simply doesn't load a window it seems when threaded!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I never used Tkinter, but Python threads are not compatible with most GUI libraries, so I guess it is the same for Tkinter.

Comment: @Valentin Lorentz I have used Tkinter before with a python thread. The GUI more basic than this one, worked perfectly fine. This is why i am confused. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood right, this is appropriate solution (change your Main Bot Code):

```
import threading
import subprocess

def create_giu():
    subprocess.call(['python', 'GUI.py'])


try:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=create_gui)
    t1.start()


except:
    print('Unable to load GUI')

#continue execution
print 1234
```

But, I think this is a bad solution in terms of software architecture.

Answer (score 0):

GUI should be in the main thread of the program, it can't execute from another thread. In the latter case it is in main thread and in the former you're trying to start if from a thread which is not main thread.